# wrong location on Google Map. cannot retrieve correct distance to next Activity

Tags: android, location, google-maps-api-2

My android app is to track user location on a map and calculate the distance and duration he has walked or run. Then when i press stop, pass it over to the next page. 
My distance and duration calculation should be correct, but the location is wrong. whether i don't move or move a few meters in my house, it sometimes never change or change a lot, result in the distance being inaccurate. how do i ensure accuracy for when i walked, even a few meters, because when i present i will be walking for a short distance.
second, i can pass my duration data over to the next page, but when i pass my distance it is 0.0 but the value shown is not 0.0 at all(got value although inaccurate). i pass my information when i press Stop button.

My MainActivity Java Code, display map, distance, duration.

```
 protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Button btnStartMove,btnPause,btnResume,btnStop;
    static double n=0;
    Long s1,r1;
    double dis=0.0;
    Thread t1;
    EditText userNumberInput;
    boolean bool=false;
    int count=0;

    double speed = 1.6;
    double lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,lat3,lon3,lat4,lon4;
    double dist = 0.0;
    double time = 0.0;
    TextView distance;
    Button btnDuration;
    float[] result;
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 4000; //in milliseconds
    boolean startDistance = false;
    boolean startButtonClicked = false;

    MyCount counter;
    int timer = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        if(isGooglePlay())
        {
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
        distance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distance);
        btnDuration=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Duration);
        btnStartMove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);//start moving
        btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Stop);

        //prepare distance...........
        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");  
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        btnStartMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");  
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                lat3 = location.getLatitude();
                lon3 = location.getLongitude();
                startButtonClicked=true;
                startDistance=true;
                counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
                counter.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                          "Pressed Start",    
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startButtonClicked=false;
                startDistance=false;
                //Double.valueOf(distance.getText().toString()
                Double value=dist;
                Double durationValue=time;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("dist", "value");
                intent.putExtra("time",durationValue);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnDuration.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(startButtonClicked=true) 
                {
                    time=n*30+r1;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Duration :"+String.valueOf(time),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }       
            }
        });

        if(location!= null)
        {
            //Display current location in Toast
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(location == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Location is null",    
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if(googleMap == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Getting map",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            googleMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

            if(googleMap != null)
            {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setUpMap() 
    {
        //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        //Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if(provider == null)
        {
            onProviderDisabled(provider);
        }
        //set map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        //Get current location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(myLocation != null)
        {
            onLocationChanged(myLocation);
        }       
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlay() 
    {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return(true);
        }
        else
        {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();

        }
        return (false);

     }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
        System.out.println("speed " + myLocation.getSpeed());

            //show location on map.................
            //Get latitude of the current location
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            //Get longitude of the current location
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            //Create a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            //Show the current location in Google Map
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            //Zoom in the Google Map
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
            //show distance............................

            if(startDistance == true)
            {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                          "Location has changed",    
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(myLocation != null)
                    {
                        //latitude.setText("Current Latitude: " + String.valueOf(loc2.getLatitude())); 
                        //longitude.setText("Current Longitude: " + String.valueOf(loc2.getLongitude()));
                        float[] results = new float[1]; 
                        Location.distanceBetween(lat3, lon3, myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), results);
                        System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);               

                        dist += results[0];            
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // adjust this as appropriate
                    if(count==1)
                    {
                        distance.setText(df.format(dist) + "meters");
                    }
                        lat3=myLocation.getLatitude();
                        lon3=myLocation.getLongitude();
                        count=1;
                  }

            }
            if(startButtonClicked == true)
            {
                startDistance=true;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    }
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
         counter.start();
         n=n+1;
        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            s1=millisUntilFinished;
            r1=(30000-s1)/1000;
        }
    }}
```

pass information to this page,distance 0.0(inaccurate) duration is ok

```
public class FinishActivity extends Activity {
TextView displayDistance;
TextView displayDuration;
TextView displaySports;
TextView userID;
TextView sportID;
TextView caloriesBurned;


Button back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");
        Double durationValue = extras.getDouble("time");
        displayDistance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishDistance);
        displayDistance.setText("Distance: " + value);

        displayDuration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishDuration);
        displayDuration.setText("Duration: " + durationValue + " seconds");

    }

    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(FinishActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });}
```

My output for my map, inaccurate location. i search for long but there seem to be no solution for this..please help..thanks. the starting location, speed where it change location, all seem to be different each time i run. it appear to be out of my control(or i can but i do not know..i'm a beginner at gps... most of the time it needs to wait a while before displaying the distance.

[image]

Comment: pls post only the relevant code. you posted the entire activity code.

Comment: also where do you calculate the distance? could you log the value of dist @ `System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);               

                        dist += results[0]; ` and check what is the value?

Comment: how do i log the value? the dist value i believe should be correct when i tested it on emulator, but main thing is it is based on the location gps detected, since the gps detected many wrong location, it will be inaccurate.

Comment: try it oustide the house

Comment: i did try it outside the house. it is better, when i walking location updated need some time but most of the surroundings seems to be correct. when i am in a car, the location seem to be better too, but i think there is still some inaccuracy. but when i present i am in a building. it is only little more(but not fully) accurate when i am moving very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gps may not work well under the roof. So try it outside the house.

Also you have

```
intent.putExtra("dist", "value")
```

key is dist

value is a string not a double

SO you are passing string

But when you get you get the double

```
Double value = extras.getDouble("dist"); // wrong
```

If you pass a double value then you can get the double in the next activity. But you pass string and then you try to get the double value and that is wrong.

What you need

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, double value)
```

and

```
public double getDoubleExtra (String name, double defaultValue)
```

Comment: thanks. my distance can be transferred over now. however, when i press back, the activity seem to restart but the duration is still accumulating. but when i press stop i call finish.

Comment: @Myst restarting is bcoz of this Intent intent = new `Intent(FinishActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();` just call finish so that you can move back to the previous activity and stop accumulating duration in the first activity when you navigate to second

Comment: @Myst stop the timer when you navigation from first to second. and just call `finish()` in second when you press `back`.

Comment: my duration can work now. i uses counter.cancel();,n=0;,r1=null,time=0.0; when i press stop. i don't think i need all of them but since it works i focus on my other problem now. the main problem is the location is is total wrong. i do not know how to make it accurate. thanks for the suggesstion though.

Comment: my location only seem to be slightly more accurate when i am in a care and is moving fast..but the purpose of the app is to track walking/running speed. when i present i at most will walk inside a room

Comment: @Myst in a room!. gps won't work well under the roof.

Comment: i would have to discuss how to deal with that during presnetation then. but when i walk outside, the location is quite inaccurate, although better then in house. then when in fast moving vechcle it becomes better. but the app is for walking/running not vehicle so how do i make it more accurate? because walking outside also need some time and there are still problems. the distance at System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]) add up seems to be equals to the accumulated distance displayed.

Comment: even if i cannot get the correct location, i wanted to show the user where he is. the blue dot is away from the red and a "you are here" should appear on the latest red marker but why it does not appear?

Comment: @Myst pls ask a new question. i have pointed the mistake that i could lay my eyes on. May be i need i need to check your code myself for further testing. better start a new thread

Comment: i have ask a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655553/ensure-location-accuracy-and-track-user-on-google-map.